# Design Linked List - Leetcode #707 - getting wrong output

Tags: java, testing, linked-list, output

I am trying to solve LeetCode problem [707. Design Linked List](https://leetcode.com/problems/design-linked-list/):

> Design your implementation of the linked list. You can choose to use a singly or doubly linked list.
>
> A node in a singly linked list should have two attributes: `val` and `next`. `val` is the value of the current node, and `next` is a pointer/reference to the next node.
>
> If you want to use the doubly linked list, you will need one more attribute `prev` to indicate the previous node in the linked list. Assume all nodes in the linked list are **0-indexed**.
>
> Implement the `MyLinkedList` class:
>
> - `MyLinkedList()` Initializes the `MyLinkedList` object.
> - `int get(int index)` Get the value of the `index`<sup>th</sup> node in the linked list. If the index is invalid, return -1.
> - `void addAtHead(int val)` Add a node of value `val` before the first element of the linked list. After the insertion, the new node will be the first node of the linked list.
> - `void addAtTail(int val)` Append a node of value `val` as the last element of the linked list.
> - `void addAtIndex(int index, int val)` Add a node of value `val` before the `index`<sup>th</sup> node in the linked list. If `index` equals the length of the linked list, the node will be appended to the end of the linked list. If `index` is greater than the length, the node **will not be inserted**.
> - `void deleteAtIndex(int index)` Delete the `index`<sup>th</sup> node in the linked list, if the `index` is valid.
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> **Input**
>
> ```
> ["MyLinkedList", "addAtHead", "addAtTail", "addAtIndex", "get", "deleteAtIndex", "get"]
> [[], [1], [3], [1, 2], [1], [1], [1]]
> ```
>
> **Output**
>
> ```
> [null, null, null, null, 2, null, 3]
> ```
>
> **Explanation**
>
> ```
> MyLinkedList myLinkedList = new MyLinkedList();
> myLinkedList.addAtHead(1);
> myLinkedList.addAtTail(3);
> myLinkedList.addAtIndex(1, 2);    // linked list becomes 1->2->3
> myLinkedList.get(1);              // return 2
> myLinkedList.deleteAtIndex(1);    // now the linked list is 1->3
> myLinkedList.get(1);              // return 3
> ```

Wondering what's wrong with my LinkedList here.

Can't get it past the input:

```
["MyLinkedList","addAtHead","addAtHead","addAtHead","addAtIndex","deleteAtIndex","addAtHead","addAtTail","get","addAtHead","addAtIndex","addAtHead"]

[[],[7],[2],[1],[3,0],[2],[6],[4],[4],[4],[5,0],[6]]
```

with my output as:

```
[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,6,null,null,null]
```

and the expected output as:

```
[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,4,null,null,null]
```

This is my implementation:

```
class DoublyListNode {   
    int val;
    DoublyListNode next;
    DoublyListNode prev;

    public DoublyListNode(int val) {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = null;
        this.prev = null;
    } 
}

class MyLinkedList {    

    DoublyListNode head;
    DoublyListNode tail;
    
    public MyLinkedList() {
       head = new DoublyListNode(-1);
       tail = new DoublyListNode(-1);

       head.next = tail;
       tail.prev = head;
    }
    
    public int get(int index) {
        DoublyListNode curr = head;
        int i = 0;

        while(tail != null && index > 0){
            curr = curr.next;
            index--;     
        }

        if(index == 0 && curr != null){
            return curr.val;
        } 
        return -1;
    }
    
    public void addAtHead(int val) {
        DoublyListNode newHead = new DoublyListNode(val);
        head.next.prev = newHead;
        head.next = newHead;
        newHead.next = head.next;
        newHead.prev = head;
    }
    
    public void addAtTail(int val) {
        DoublyListNode newTail = new DoublyListNode(val);

        tail.prev.next = newTail;
        tail.prev = newTail;
        newTail.next = tail;
        newTail.prev = tail.prev;
    }
    
    public void addAtIndex(int index, int val) {
        DoublyListNode curr = head;

        while(tail != null && index > 0){
            curr = curr.next;
            index--;
        }

        if(index == 0 && curr != null){
            DoublyListNode newNode = new DoublyListNode(val);
            newNode.prev = curr.prev;
            newNode.next = curr.next;
            curr.prev.next = newNode;
            curr.next.prev = newNode;
        }
    }
    
    public void deleteAtIndex(int index) {            
        DoublyListNode curr = head;

        while(tail != null && index > 0){
            curr = curr.next;
            index--;
        }
        if(index == 0 && curr != null && curr.next != null && curr.prev != null){
            curr.prev.next = curr.next;
            curr.next.prev = curr.prev;
        }
    }
}    

/**
 * Your MyLinkedList object will be instantiated and called as such:
 * MyLinkedList obj = new MyLinkedList();
 * int param_1 = obj.get(index);
 * obj.addAtHead(val);
 * obj.addAtTail(val);
 * obj.addAtIndex(index,val);
 * obj.deleteAtIndex(index);
 */
```

Answer (score 3):

You have chosen to implement a doubly linked list, with two dummy (sentinal) nodes, `head` and `tail`.

This is fine, but there are several issues in your code:

- In `get`, `addAtIndex` and `deleteAtIndex`, you start with `curr` equal to `head`, which means that if the given index is 0, `curr` will still be that `head`, while the node at index 0 really is the *successor* of your `head`. `head` doesn't count as node, as it is a dummy node. So you should start with `curr = head.next` instead of `curr = head`. As a consequence, in `deleteAtIndex`, you don't need the last part of the `if` condition (`curr.prev != null`), as this is now guaranteed.
- In the same three functions you have a loop condition that says `tail != null`, but this condition is always true. `tail` never is assigned anything else after its initialisation in the constructor (and it shouldn't). The loop condition should instead test `curr != null`.
- In `addAtHead` you have wired the nodes incorrectly. The assignment `head.next = newHead;` should happen *after* `newHead.next = head.next;`, because as you have it now, you make `newHead.next` to become equal to `newHead`, introducing a cycle in your list.
- In `addAtTail` the order of assignments is also in the wrong order. You make `newTail.prev` equal to `newTail`, introducing a cycle.
- In `addAtIndex` there are two wrong assignments. The first two would attempt to *exclude* `curr` from the list, but it should become the neighbor of the new node. Therefore you should do `newNode.next = curr;` instead of `newNode.next = curr.next;`. `curr.next.prev = newNode;` is also wrong, as this link should not be updated. It could even lead to an exception, because `curr` could be equal to the tail node, which has a `null` for its `next` field. Instead you should do `curr.prev = newNode;`

Not a problem, but in `get` you have declared an unused variable `i`. You can drop it.

Here is your code with the above corrections applied to it (see comments in code):

```java
class DoublyListNode {
    int val;
    DoublyListNode next;
    DoublyListNode prev;

    public DoublyListNode(int val) {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = null;
        this.prev = null;
    } 
}

class MyLinkedList {    
    DoublyListNode head;
    DoublyListNode tail;
    
    public MyLinkedList() {
        head = new DoublyListNode(-1);
        tail = new DoublyListNode(-1);

        head.next = tail;
        tail.prev = head;
    }
    
    public int get(int index) {
        DoublyListNode curr = head.next; // This is the node at index 0
        
        while (curr != null && index > 0) { // Corrected loop condition
            curr = curr.next;
            index--;
        }

        if (index == 0 && curr != null) {
            return curr.val;
        }
        return -1;
    }
    
    public void addAtHead(int val) {
        DoublyListNode newHead = new DoublyListNode(val);
        // Fixed the order of the assignments: 
        newHead.next = head.next;
        newHead.prev = head;
        head.next.prev = newHead;
        head.next = newHead;
    }
    
    public void addAtTail(int val) {
        DoublyListNode newTail = new DoublyListNode(val);
        // Fixed the order of the assignments: 
        newTail.next = tail;
        newTail.prev = tail.prev;
        tail.prev.next = newTail;
        tail.prev = newTail;
    }
    
    public void addAtIndex(int index, int val) {
        DoublyListNode curr = head.next; // This is the node at index 0

        while (curr != null && index > 0){ // Corrected loop condition
            curr = curr.next;
            index--;
        }

        if (index == 0 && curr != null) {
            DoublyListNode newNode = new DoublyListNode(val);
            newNode.prev = curr.prev;
            newNode.next = curr; // Corrected assignment
            curr.prev.next = newNode;
            curr.prev = newNode; // Corrected assignment
        }
    }
    
    public void deleteAtIndex(int index) {            
        DoublyListNode curr = head.next; // This is the node at index 0

        while (curr != null && index > 0) { // Corrected loop condition
            curr = curr.next;
            index--;
        }
        if (index == 0 && curr != null && curr.next != null) { // Removed obsolete condition
            curr.prev.next = curr.next;
            curr.next.prev = curr.prev;
        }
    }
}
```

As a next step, you could try to remove some code repetition, as you have essentially the same loop in three of these methods.

Comment: I don't quite understand the assignment of `curr = head.next` in `get`. If a get(0) is called, wouldn't that mean your implementation will be returning get(1) instead since it is getting the next node in the list rather than the first one?

Comment: What you call the first one is the `head` node. It is a dummy node you have created. It doesn't count as a node that really has data. Realise that your list implementation already starts with creating two nodes (`head` and `tail`) even though it should be regarded as an empty list.

Comment: Did that answer your question?

Comment: Ah yes, I'm not the question asker and didn't look closely at the code but I see your point now